# simpleCart.checkout() throws this.create is not a function

Tags: javascript

I use simpleCart. I try start checkout process so I do

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    simpleCart.checkout();
})
</script>
```

but I get this.create is not a function Line: 1385. Any idea why that can happen? Here is link http://nmse.edge1.net/order-online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simpleCart(js) requires using jQuery, Prototype, or Mootools.